# Is it allowed to write a review on every chapter of a book?

Tags: book, reviews

It is difficult to summarize an entire book only in a single book review, when I want to have the ability of navigating through it later in my life, as a way of revising/going back for the data I took into me. I am thinking to write review on every chapter of a book or certain chapters together, depending on the density of content. Is it allowed to do that? Would there be any problem considering legal rules?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. What do you mean by "allowed"? Is this for yourself? posting on a blog? publishing in a newspaper or magazine?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, it is for posting on my blog...

Comment: I meant to ask whether there is any restriction due to copyright or law, for writing long reviews, which may expose more data...

Comment: ....I want to know whether reviewing at a long length is allowed by law.

Comment: I will be analyzing the content, which will help me and the author. Review will be for both, me and author/publisher.

Comment: We are not copyright lawyers here. But generally speaking, anyone can review anything at length on a blog. *Quoting* may have some limitations; I'm not sure how much you're allowed to quote before getting into trouble. But you can write as much as you like if you're discussing, reviewing, and analyzing a work without reproducing it.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: Thank you! You could have wrote that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, quotation for purposes of criticism is an allowed use under copyright law. That does not necessarily mean all quotation in a review is permitted usage, though. You should make sure it is genuinely done for the sake of critique. But IANAL and there are plenty of better resources on permitted use available.